Are 'Alice and Bob’ too ‘Western’ and in need of modernisation?
Reference this article regarding (UK) University of Edinburgh’s efforts to eliminate the use of 'Alice and Bob' in cryptography.  And replacing 'Master /Slave' nomenclature within computer architecture. Seemingly it's decolonization, but that definition doesn't seem quite appropriate.
Too much, or the time for a re-examination here? And if so, how /who /what would Alice and Bob's successors be called?

This is not entirely a serious question; more contextual information regarding the incoming tide.

Given the sensitivity of the subject, I guess any question about it needs to be taken seriously.

Thanks for the topic. I rather found this as.

Well, A and B and E. I'm pretty sure that if my name was Alice, Bob, or Eve, I would definitely make lots of funs during lecturing.

@kelalaka I suspect the intention is for more cultural diversity, not just abbreviating existing Western names. And they're not even 'Western' names, they're English names. I wouldn't mind an evil/anti-hero type 'Paweł' spy listening in and selling his ill gotten data to the highest bidder.  It's kinda sexy.  That's Paul in Polish. Or perhaps he could be the new trustworthy 'Trent'.

You look in your perspective like me. IMHO, Bond is a good spy name, A disagree with Paul since there are lots of pope names on this, and it will create another problem like eve-Eve.

@kelalaka No I meant the Polish spelling. That would include the Poles.

In Japanese, I use "me" and "the other party".  私と相手の人.  Alice and Bob are fine in a western context.  Chinese also has a similar structure.  I won't get too woke up about it.

@bdegnan interesting, I've never thought that Alice and Bon are non-universal.

In Chinese, there's the 甲乙丙丁戊... ideogram-based "numbering". The most common ones don't have any positive or negative connotation, so I don't think it can cover the names of adversaries such as Eve or Mallory.

There's one name that has "criminal" connotation - 张三. This name is used as a placeholder for the "suspect" and the "accused" in law enforcement eductional videos found on BiliBili, Youku, TikTok, and several other video sharing services in China. I suppose this name can be used for the adversary.

@kelalaka And so the basis of critical race theory...

@PaulUszak it is not about that, I never said everyone must use it, and everybody is free to use whatever they wanted. It existed in eastern documents so it was natural to adopt it in that way. Even the academicians in the world use it in their paper, so it was expected to be Alice, Bob. etc. Indeed I'm against the eve since it may represent a religious name, too, though it is short for the eavesdropper.

It's about annihilation, neither Alice, Bob, nor Cryptography.

@kelalaka Just teasing, but you thought "Alice" was a common name in Khmer (Cambodia)?

@SamGinrich Most here will know that I'm incredibly broad minded and that I don't give a flying 'uck about anything, but I'm not quite sure what you mean about annihilation. So post a full answer and we'll vote on it :-)

Understanding Maarten's comment and the fact, that you have not got a single formal response, does not require very much of ´incredibly broad minded´. ;)
